# Java only returns 0 when equation is unfactorable

Tags: java, formula, equation, quadratic

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class QuadraticEquation
{
   private int a, b, c, d, s1, s2;

   public QuadraticEquation()
   {
      a = 1;
      b = 2;
      c = 1;
      d = 0;
      s1 = -1;
      s1 = -1;
   }

   public QuadraticEquation(int a, int b, int c)
   {
      this.a = a;
      this.b = b;
      this.c = c;
   }

   public int findDiscriminant(int a, int b, int c)
   {
      this.d = (int)Math.pow(b,2) - (4*a*c);
      return this.d;
   }

   public boolean equalRoots()
   {
      if (getSolution1() == getSolution2())
      {
         return true;
      } else {
         return false;
      }
   }

   public boolean noSolution()
   {
      if (Math.sqrt(this.d) == 0)
      {
         return false;
      } else {
         return true;
      }
   }

   public int getSolution1()
   {
      this.s1 = (int)(-b + Math.sqrt(this.d))/(2*a);
      return this.s1;
   }

   public int getSolution2()
   {
      this.s2 = (int)(-b - Math.sqrt(this.d))/(2*a);
      return this.s2;
   }

   public static void main (String args[])
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
      for (int k = 1; k <= 3; k++)
      {
         System.out.print("Enter a, b, and c: ");
         int a = input.nextInt();
         int b = input.nextInt();
         int c = input.nextInt();

         QuadraticEquation q = new QuadraticEquation(a,b,c);

         if (q.noSolution() == true)
         {
            System.out.println("No real solution");
         } else if (q.equalRoots() == true) {
            System.out.println("The only solution is: " + q.getSolution1());
         } else {
            System.out.println("The two real solutions are: ");
            System.out.println(q.getSolution1());
            System.out.println(q.getSolution2());
         } //Else
      } //For
   } //Main
} //QuadraticEquations
```

I have this code, and I'm trying to get the factors of an equation. If the solutions aren't integers, then it returns "No real solution". If the factors are the same, then it returns the only factor. If there are two factors, then it should return two factors. It works when there's only 1 factor, (ex. when a=1, b=2, and c=1), but it doesn't work when the equation is unfactorable, and when there's two solutions, it only returns 1.

Here is current incorrect output:

```
 ----jGRASP exec: java QuadraticEquation
Enter a, b, and c: 1 1 1
The only solution is: 0
Enter a, b, and c: 
 ----jGRASP: process ended by user.

 ----jGRASP exec: java QuadraticEquation
Enter a, b, and c: 1 -5 6
The only solution is: 2
Enter a, b, and c: 
 ----jGRASP: process ended by user.

 ----jGRASP exec: java QuadraticEquation
Enter a, b, and c: 1 2 1
The only solution is: -1
Enter a, b, and c: 
 ----jGRASP: process ended by user.

 ----jGRASP exec: java QuadraticEquation
Enter a, b, and c: 1 -4 4
The only solution is: 2
Enter a, b, and c:
```

EDIT:

Thanks to bcsb1001, I've revised my code, and it works.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class QuadraticEquation
{
   private int a, b, c, d;

   public QuadraticEquation(int a, int b, int c)
   {
      this.a = a;
      this.b = b;
      this.c = c;
      this.d = findDiscriminant(a, b, c);
   }

   public int findDiscriminant(int a, int b, int c)
   {
      return (int)Math.pow(b,2) - (4*a*c);
   }

   public boolean equalRoots()
   {
      return this.d == 0;
   }

   public boolean noSolution()
   {
      return this.d < 0;
   }

   public int getSolution1()
   {
      return (int)(-b + Math.sqrt(this.d))/(2*a);
   }

   public int getSolution2()
   {
      return (int)(-b - Math.sqrt(this.d))/(2*a);
   }

   public static void main (String args[])
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
      for (int k = 1; k <= 3; k++)
      {
         System.out.print("Enter a, b, and c: ");
         int a = input.nextInt();
         int b = input.nextInt();
         int c = input.nextInt();

         QuadraticEquation q = new QuadraticEquation(a,b,c);

         if (q.noSolution() == true)
         {
            System.out.println("No real solution");
         } else if (q.equalRoots() == true) {
            System.out.println("The only solution is: " + q.getSolution1());
         } else {
            System.out.println("The two real solutions are: ");
            System.out.println(q.getSolution1());
            System.out.println(q.getSolution2());
         } //Else
      } //For
   } //Main
} //QuadraticEquations
```

Btw, I was forced to do certain things like create "findDiscriminant" because the worksheet forced me to. It gave me the main method and I was supposed to figure out everything from there.

Comment: Are you using an IDE? It should warn you about things like using `== true` (always redundant) and `if (condition) return true; else return false;` which can be replaced with `return condition;`.

Comment: I think so. I believe I had it downloaded, and I'm using JGrasp. Doesn't warn me about it though. And the "return condition;" is something I'm not really familiar with it, so I just use "if (condition return true; else return false;". I guess I should get familiar with it since its compact.

Comment: Please don't use stack snippets (that button with the `<>` symbol that you seem to be using) for Java code. It is intended for JavaScript/HTML/CSS code that can be run in the browser. Java is not the same as JavaScript. You should instead paste in your code, highlight it and either press ctrl+K or click the `{}` button to format it as code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic code logic is faulty.

`equalRoots()` should be called `hasOnlyOneSolution` and should be exactly
 `return this.d == 0`.

`noSolution()` should simply be `return this.d < 0`.

And note that you **never** call `findDiscriminant` which causes `d` to remain 0.

This is the basic mathematical distinction you make when working this problem out on paper. And the exact same logic has to be done in code.

---

Final note: you are mixing up fields and local variables like crazy. Why does `findDiscriminant` return something AND set `d`. And why does it get passed `a`, `b` and `c` instead of simply accessing the fields of the same name with hopefully the same content?

---

```
public class QuadraticEquation {
    private int a, b, d;

    public QuadraticEquation(int a, int b, int c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.d = b * b - (4 * a * c);
    }

    public boolean hasOnlyOneSolution() {
        return d == 0;
    }

    public boolean noSolution() {
        return d < 0;
    }

    public int getSolution1() {
        return (int) (-b + Math.sqrt(this.d)) / (2 * a);
    }

    public int getSolution2() {
        return (int) (-b - Math.sqrt(this.d)) / (2 * a);
    }

    // + your main method
}
```

Comment: @Blake thank you for the edit. And thank you for contributing to SO, welcome :)